# Ioinic Azure Active Directory Integration

Tags: angular, azure, authentication, ionic-framework, azure-active-directory

We would like to extend our Angular Web Application to Mobile Application with Ionic framework. After checking the offical document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc. It do not have the integration with hybrid application.

We had tried to use the SPA login flow but it only work on our web view and keep redirect our application to web page in mobile view. May I ask is this the only way we can use to do the authenitcaion by the REST API although it is not suggested by Microsoft because of security issue https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow to integrate Azure Active Directory in ionic/cordova angular apps
by using below plugins

1. @azure/msal-angular
2. @azure/msal-browser
3. cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

with [CustomNavigationClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69391322/ionic-and-msal-authentication)