# Ionic 7 and MSAL Authentication in appbrowser cordova or capacitor?

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, msal-angular

I am working on ionic 6 with capacitor (https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/browser) implementing msal integration.

Does it work with capacitor inappbrowser or cordova inppbrowser?

As per the link
[Ionic and MSAL Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69391322/ionic-and-msal-authentication/) where it is mentioned that the approach of creating customNavigationClient is working in android, requesting anyone to explain more on the below points.

1. I am using msalService.loginredirect()
2. Where I have to set this this.msalService.instance.setNavigationClient(new CustomNavigationClient(this.iab)) ?
3. Is it in the login click method login()?
4. If yes for the above question 3, do i need to set the navigationclient as mentioned in point 2 and call loginredirect as mentioned in point 1 immediately after that?
5. If not what is the approach?

Requesting anyone to assist me as I am blocked to proceed further on the implementation.

Comment: Changed the same @Yunnosch

Comment: Asking a question with a link to a different question which is your context is well done. Thanks.