# AADSTS9002326: Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type. Request origin: 'capacitor://localhost'

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, azure-ad-b2c, capacitor

I have an Ionic app that needs to authenticate in Azure and i follow this stackoverflow:
[Ionic and MSAL Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69391322/ionic-and-msal-authentication)

All did go fine except for iOS where im getting

**AADSTS9002326: Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type. Request origin: 'capacitor://localhost'**

I did try register this url on mobile and computer urls as SPA needs to have http or https so this is not valid...

Anyone knows how to fix this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The error "***Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type***" usually occurs if the Microsoft Entra ID application is not configured as SPA and you are making use of SPA authentication.

In your case, as your redirecting URL is **`capacitor://localhost`**, you cannot configure it as SPA as SPA supports only http or https. Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/reply-url#supported-schemes).

Hence **to resolve the error,** either you have to configure the application as Mobile and desktop application and use your custom **`capacitor://localhost`** redirect URL:

[image]

For *sample*:

```swift
let config = MSALPublicClientApplicationConfig(clientId: "your-client-id",
redirectUri: "your-customredirect-uri",
authority: authority)
do {
  let application = try MSALPublicClientApplication(configuration: config)
 } catch let error as NSError {
 }
```

**Otherwise**, if you want to make use of **SPA authentication**, then you need to make use of some other redirect URL https or http and configure the application as Single-page application:

[image]

```js
browser.on('loadstart').subscribe(event => {
  if (event.url.includes('code')) {
    browser.close();
    const domain = event.url.split('#')[0];
    const url = event.url.replace(domain, 'http://***');
    console.log('will redirect to:', url);
    window.location.href = url;
  }
});
```

- **By default,** you cannot add custom redirect URL to the SPA platform.

**Reference:**

[Use redirect URIs with MSAL (iOS/macOS) - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/redirect-uris-ios)

Comment: Thank you for asnwer, i solved by using my web server url as redirect uri!